# C# - adding a References directory to my project that is called "bin" just like in games installs?

Tags: c#

i would like to add a "bin" directory (just like in games install directories) that will include all the non-default Assemblies (only assemblies i add, and not things like System.Windows.Forms)

Comment: Yea I'm not sure what your asking, but I usually add a "Ref" folder and copy any assemblies that I want to reference in there.

Comment: This is default behaviour when creating a C# application. System.Windows.Forms isn't ever copied to the output directly, the reference is taken from the GAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, what you are looking for is post-build events.

This article does a great job of summing them up:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx

I used them awhile back to do something similar to what you are asking (where I wanted certain compiled assemblies to exist in a folder besides bin and debug).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

i know its very old thread. but, adding answer if anybody looking into this.

- Add reference from anywhere on hard drive.
- click on reference go to
- properties -> copy to local -> set to true if false

so that visual studio will copy file to bin while building your. project